# unable to identify current visible card in CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, classcastexception, cardlayout

i have a JPanel like:

```
public class CardLayoutPanel extends JPanel {
String[] option = {"login", "register"}    
public CardLayoutPanel() {
    super();
    combo_box = new JComboBox(option);
    login_panel = new LoginForm();
    register_panel = new RegisterForm();

    layout = new CardLayout();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(layout);

    this.add(combo_box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    panel.add(login_panel, "login");
    panel.add(register_panel, "register");

    layout.show(panel, "login");
    combo_box.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox source = (JComboBox) e.getSource();

            if(source.getSelectedItem().equals("login")) {
                layout.show(panel, "login");
            }else if(source.getSelectedItem().equals("register")) {
                layout.show(panel, "register");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

and i call from my main calss inside a JOptionPane

```
CardLayoutPanel card_panel = new CardLayoutPanel();

    int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, card_panel, "Login/Registrati",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Now, if i try to obtain the current visible card like

```
if(res == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        for(Component comp : card_panel.getComponents()) {
            if(comp.isVisible() == true) {
                JPanel current_panel = (JPanel) comp;

                System.out.println(current_panel.getName());
            }
        }
    }else if(res == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

i obtain the sequent error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JComboBox cannot be cast to javax.swing.JPanel

on this row inside for each statement:

```
JPanel current_panel = (JPanel) comp;
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: `"how can I fix it?"` -- don't cast a JComboBox to a JPanel. Cast it to a JComboBox and use it as a JComboBox.

Comment: but why it cast component into JComboBox and not into Jpanel?

Comment: `but why it cast component into JComboBox and not into Jpanel?` - Your code is wrong and you haven't posted a SSCCE so we can't tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Because it's not a JPanel. You should not be going through the components as you're doing but rather you should be using reference variables that allow you to extract the JComboBox and thereby query its state.

Comment: @giozh : Add `(comp instanceOf JPanel) && (comp.isVisible())` to your if condition, then I guess it can work :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply get the JComboBox and query its selected item. Assuming that the class that holds the JComboBox has a method say called, `getComboBox()`:

```
JComboBox combo = getComboBox();
String selectedItem = combo.getSelectedItem().toString();
System.out.println(selectedItem);
```

Alternatively and probably better for the class that holds the combo box to have a method that doesn't expose the combo box itself but allows other classes to query the combobox for the selected item.

```
public Object getComboBoxSelection() {
  combo_box.getSelectedItem();
}
```

And then outside classes can call this method on a valid reference.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure you are using the CardLayout correctly. I don't know why you would add a CardLayout to a JOptionPane. I would just add the panel you want to display.

But if you really want to know the currently display card in a CardLayout then check out
[Card Layout Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/) which has a method to do this.